# Customizing wordpress default widgets?

Tags: widgets, date, recent-posts

Is there anyway to customize the default WordPress widgets or do i need to create my own? For example, I want my recent post widgets to display date aswell.

Thanks in advance!

/Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create your own but you can copy the code and customize from /wp-includes/default-widgets.php

If you edit the defaults they'll screw up when you update WP.